# Shotgun damage for different shotguns and ammo types

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to know if the different shotguns have differing amounts of damage they do (and if they vary at range). I also would like to know if the different ammo types cause relatively different damage levels for different shot guns. For example, does a USAS slug round cause less/more damage than a DAO slug round? Also, if there are differences, has anyone actually quantified those differences? Does anyone have information on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shotgun only determines the accuracy, rate of fire, recoil, bullet drop, bullet velocity, etc., i.e. they determine how a round is fired. Damage is entirely based on the type of round being fired. This is true for all guns in BF3.

Like most games with range factoring in to the damage equation, rounds do maximum damage within a certain range, and then damage decreases linearly until a certain point, after which damage will be the minimum amount.

Frag rounds (semi-auto): 20 damage within 8 meters, 10 at or past 40 meters

Frag rounds (pump action): 60 damage within 8 meters, 10 at or past 40 meters

Additionally, frag rounds to 30 explosive splash damage within 1.5 meters, decreasing linearly to 0 at 3 meters.

Slug rounds (semi-auto): 50 damage within 8 meters, 34 at or past 40 meters

Slug rounds (pump action): 100 damage within 8 meters, 34 at or past 40 meters

Buckshot rounds: 20 damage within 4 meters, 6 at or past 25 meters

Flechette: 14.3 damage within 12 meters, 8.4 at or past 25 meters

Stats are from http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=dmgchart, and may change in future updates.

Comment: You're welcome. As I understand it, that site is actually given the game data directly from DICE, unlike other game's I've played where someone had to dig through the game's code. Also, besides the damage charts, I find the accuracy charts quite interesting. They make it much easier to get a sense of how a weapon's true accuracy is derived from the recoil, spread, and fire rate.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could upvote again just for the link. Very good information there. Also helps me understand why certain guns suddenly are getting used all the time (like the M26 Dart).